# Divide a colunm for the other to reach a percentual value in a pivot table

Tags: excel, dax, pivot-table

I have the following data:
[image: print of the table]

colunm A, B and C, have a different target, and i wanted the running total as a percentual of this target.

example, colunm A target is 2.500.000,00 so in FW 2023-16 we are at a 98% in the target.

I tried some DAX on this, but ended up in nothing. Im a DAX noob btw

I need this done in a pivot table so I can faster update the data base and my charts.

This target value of 2.500.000,00, i need to add him on my data source as a new colunm?

Can someone help me? Thanks!